# libuv: what's the int returned by uv_tcp_connect?

Tags: c, return-value, libuv

Consider the [documentation](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/tcp.html) of `uv_tcp_connect`.
Here is the declaration of the function:

```
int uv_tcp_connect(uv_connect_t* req, uv_tcp_t* handle, const struct sockaddr* addr, uv_connect_cb cb);
```

It accepts a callback and returns an integer.
Usually, the other functions in *libuv* returns an error code (0 in case of no errors).
I guess also this one works the same way.

What is unclear to me (and undocumented as well) is: in case of a return value not equal to 0, will the callback be invoked anyway?
In other terms, does a return value different from 0 mean that the operation won't be performed at all or it is guaranteed that the callback is invoked?

Unfortunately, it seems that it is not documented what the return value actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [error handling section](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/errors.html) in the documentation. An error (return < 0) means no operation will be performed and no callback will be called.

Comment: There is no sentence like the one you mentioned in that section.

Comment: Ouch, I would've sworn it was there (I wrote that). Fixing that! https://github.com/libuv/libuv/pull/918

Comment: Thanks. [My C++ wrapper](https://github.com/skypjack/uvw) is benefitting from this information. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In case it returns non-zero result it will not call a callback.

You can check this thread for more details:

https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/391

Answer (score 0):

[From reading the source](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/src/unix/tcp.c#L140):

- The return value is a (negative) error code, 0 means all went fine.
- The code with non-zero return paths don't reference the callback, so I don't think it will be invoked on error.